# Why is my Apache welcome page not loading in Microsoft Azure?

Tags: azure, apache, lamp

I am facing as issue regarding the LAMP stck that I installed in a Virtual Machine of Microsoft Azure. After installing I checked if apache is really installed or not with Apache2 -V terminal command. it shows the server version and built. But when I try to open it with public IP address in web browser that is given in the "overview" section of Azure, it gives following error...
"20.204.21.231 took too long to respond."

I have searched verious forms. chatGPT and Bard as well. Tried all sorts of posible fix but no one worked. I tried to change the owner of the var/www/html folder to the "azureuser". I also provided the required writable and executable permission to the folder. See screenshot for reference.

[image]

I assume the issue is with the Azure clound itself where I need to make some configuration changes. So, I need help from people who have worked with Apache in Azure clouds who can help me with this issue.

Comment: did you open the required inbound ports for VM?

Comment: Yeah, figured it out. I haven't enabled port 80 from Azure CLI. thanks.

Comment: Please review *[Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/)* (e.g., *"Images should only be used to illustrate problems that* ***can't be made clear in any other way,*** *such as to provide screenshots of a user interface."*) and [do the right thing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76399290/edit). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I tried installing Ubuntu virtual machine on Microsoft Azure and was able to get the welcome page successfully using the below steps:

To install  Apache on a virtual machine, you can run the below command:

```
sudo  apt install apache2
```

Make sure to check if Apache is running or not using the below command:

```
sudo service apache2 status
```

[image]

If Apache is not running, you can start it with the following command:

```
sudo service apache2 start
```

Double-check that your virtual machine's network security group allows incoming traffic on **port 80 (HTTP)** like this:

*Go to Azure Portal -> Your virtual machine -> Networking -> Inbound security rules*

[image]

Make sure that the Apache configuration is set up correctly. Check the following file:  `/etc/apache2/ports.conf`. Ensure that the Listen directive is set to **80**.

[image]

When I tried to access the website using the public IP address,  I got **Apache welcome page** successfully like below:

[image]

Comment: I had missed enabling port 80 from Azure CLI. Figured it out after several trials and errors. Thanks for the response.